# Crash on disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

My app has started crashing on `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal = true`
in my view controller on iOS 9.3.5 and earlier.

I'm getting:

`-[ViewController setDisablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Is there an elegant way to work around this problem? I'm using Swift in my project.

Comment: You have to override this  your viewController `func disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal() -> Bool' {
    return true
}`

Comment: I'm much more interested in why this crashes now on iOS 8 but not on iOS 10? Though, no specific API warnings are given. It used to work fine before I updated my app with Xcode 8.

Comment: I think @jatinkumarmalana points in the right direction. I overwrite the property and it works. But you must provide the get and the set method! I ended up with:    override var disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal: Bool {
        get { return false }
        set {  }
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's a bug. Something like this should never happen.

Also, the correct way of using this API seems to be overriding this property of a `UIViewController`, not setting its value.

```
override var disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal: Bool { 
    get { return true } // or false
    set { }
}
```

*Thanks to matzino for the tip.*

Comment: @matzino no. I removed this line from my code. I also had no response from Apple regarding this problem.

Comment: @matzino maybe you should try to override `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal` property of UIViewController instead of setting a value. I never tried it, but I thought it could work.

Comment: yep that fixed it for me :) I commented it also on your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is also anther way to dismiss keyboard. you just need to write

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

when you need to require dismiss keyboard.